# CodePipeline/CodeDeploy move files from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm using aws-cdk for my architecture and I need one last piece to the puzzle. Is it possible to move files from S3 to specific directories on the EC2 instance?

I have my .env file and nginx config files in an S3 bucket and once the update has rolled out using CodePipeline/CodeDeploy I want to move the files into their place. I don't want to manage these files on GitHub or by having to SSH into the instance.

// appspec.yml

```
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /path/to/webserverdir
```

Can I use S3 as a source?

Comment: Copying the S3 content can be part of the CodeDeploy script ran by the CodeDeploy agent. What is the problem, what is not clear or working?

Comment: How? I cannot figure out how to copy files over to the EC2 instance.

Comment: What is your `appspec.yml` that tries to copy the files? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin Updated original question with contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use S3 as a source?

Sadly, you can't. You have to write **bash/powershell script** which is going to use AWS CLI to perform the copy from S3 to the instance. Then you invoke the script as part of your `appspec.yml`. In addition to this, your instances will need to have an instance role with **permissions to S3**.

Comment: Thank you. I ended going this route and it works fine after allowing permissions as you stated.

Comment: @JuanRangel No problem. Glad it worked out :-)